# Partially superposing data in lattice's xyplot()

Tags: r, panel, lattice

Please, reproduce this code:

```
install.packages('lattice')
install.packages('zoo')
require(lattice)
require(zoo)
X <- matrix(runif(25 * 8), ncol = 8)
```

(Its purpose is just to load packages and to create a matrix with 8 columns).

Using `zoo` it is very easy to create such a plot:

```
plot.zoo(X, screen = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), col = c(1,2))
```

[image: Example plot]

How can I make the same with `lattice`'s `xyplot()` function?

Comment: `latticeExtra` doesn't have an `xyplot` plot function.  Maybe you meant `zoo:::xyplot.zoo`.  There are lots of examples in `?xyplot.zoo`.  What did you try?

Comment: Sorry, GSee, it was just the `lattice` package function. Title's edited.

Comment: It still appears that you haven't attempted to solve this yourself.

Comment: Done with `zoo:::xyplot.zoo`. Thank you. Maybe you should provide a short answer in order to not let this question unanswered..?

Comment: Great!  Please answer your own question ([it's encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)) and after the mandatory waiting period, accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done via `zoo:::xyplot.zoo`: as reported in `zoo` package documentation, `xyplot.zoo` has `xyplot` methods for time series objects.

Then, for what concerns the above question, it is possible to use:

```
xyplot(as.zoo(X), screen = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), col = c(1,2))
```

to produce a `trellis` object like in `lattice` selecting the desired layout with the `screen` argument.